# making application System Critical Process

Tags: c#, .net, process

how can i make a Critical System Process so that it can't be ended from task manager in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, it is not possible to do so because it would take away control from the user. Windows even allows you to kill highly critical processes such as csrss.exe (don't try killing it, please, instant BSOD is guaranteed).

The very good reasons why this is so have been very well explained by Raymond Chen:

> **[The arms race between programs and users](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx)**

If you don't want users to kill your process make it a service and take away administrator privileges from your users.

Comment: I agree that this is more a user security issue and not an application issue.  On kiosk systems we've deployed, we use gpedit.msc to simply disable the Task Manager for the User login account.

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Would restricting Task Manager also restrict users from accessing http://live.sysinternals.com/procexp.exe?

Comment: no, though in our particular case, we bypassed executing explorer.exe entirely, replacing it with the kiosk UI.  As such, the User could not launch any programs.  The Task Manager restriction was mainly to prevent trouble if a User plugged in a keyboard and didn't have the Administrator password to service the machine.

Answer (score 2):

may be a little late but this is the code I use

```
    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern void RtlSetProcessIsCritical(UInt32 v1, UInt32 v2, UInt32 v3);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    private static extern bool SetKernelObjectSecurity(
         IntPtr handle,
         int securityInformation,
         [In] byte[] securityDescriptor
     );
```

calling the function on C#

```
RtlSetProcessIsCritical(1, 0, 0);
```

just note that

- you need administrator for this
- causes BSOD whenever you close the process

to go back to normal just do

```
RtlSetProcessIsCritical(0, 0, 0);
```